# My Mac Service deactivates the foreground app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've written a Cocoa Service in a Mac app. When I'm in another app and I trigger the service, even if the service code is completely empty:

```
- (void)doMyService:(NSPasteboard*)pasteboard
        userData:(NSString*)userData 
        error:(NSString**)error {
}
```

... that app's window is deactivated and mine is brought forward. This is true even if my app is set to run in dockless mode (LSUIElement = false). The foreground app's window is deactivated even if my app has no window of its own!

I've tried deactivating my app in the service handler; no luck. Hiding my app from within the service handler seems to work, but only if the user triggers the service with the context menu, not the key combo, and only if we're not running in dockless mode (I want my app to be dockless).

How do I either prevent the foreground app from deactivating, or at the very least be able to reactivate it?

Comment: Set "Application is background only" to yes in plist file of your service.

Comment: What is your service doing? Does it quit when it completes its task?

Comment: @parag Thanks for the suggestion, however it seems to have no effect.

Comment: @RobKeniger It's taking the text grabbed by the Service and sending it to a web api. I don't want it to quit after each time, because we also have a status bar icon/menu that I want to stick around.

On normal operation, just a Growl notification is sufficient; I don't need my app to come forward at all. On occasion I might need to throw up a window so the user can log into the web api, but even then I'll want to be able to return to the previous app once the window is dismissed.

Answer (score 4):

OK this question is 6 months old so you've probably solved your problem by now, but in case this is useful...

I solved a similar problem with an app I'm working on by observing application deactivations via NSWorkspace.

You could have a property:

```
NSRunningApplication* _previousRunningApplication;
```

And update this property by observing the NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
                                                       selector:@selector(anyApplicationDeactivated:)
                                                           name:NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification
                                                         object:nil];


// Called when any running application deactivates
-(void)anyApplicationDeactivated:(NSNotification*) notification {
    NSRunningApplication* app = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:NSWorkspaceApplicationKey];
    _previousRunningApplication = app;
}
```

Then when your app finishes executing, just activate the previously active app using:

```
// Activate the previously active application (if available)
[_previousRunningApplication activateWithOptions:0];
```

If there's any chance that last line could be called while your app *isn't* active, then it should first check it is using `[NSApp isActive]` (or you could trigger some surprising, and annoying, behaviour for users...)

If you found a simpler solution I'd be interested in hearing about it.

In case this code is useful to anyone, I've created a separate class to handle it all and checked it into Github:

http://github.com/mjrit/MJRAppReactivation

Comment: I have in fact moved on, but thanks for the answer! Seems there has been some interest in this issue, so hopefully it'll help the next person avoid some headbanging.